# Angular 6 read http request header on load

Tags: angular, typescript, http

in Angular 6/7, is there a way to read the request header on application load.

I need to read header values as Security access management set values in header while accessing angular app.

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(){
    // Read http request header here
   }
```

Comment: The header of *what* request? And which headers? If they're security-related, they may not be accessible to *any* JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: Header of the initial request of the application. It will be through a security management system like ISAM, where it will have the logged in users group information

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the headers the server sent up when it responded to the original browser request, it appears to me that only the cookies are available: you can retrieve them via [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)